# Permission denied when running npm i gulp-cli g for a Bootstrap theme

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, gulp

I'm trying to install a new bootstrap theme locally and install the javascript packages with npm as per the theme's instructions: https://prium.github.io/twbs-sparrow/documentation/getting-started.html

However, when i run the code, I get an error about permissions:

```
 MacBook:node_modules HeatherDannyelle$ npm i gulp-cli -g
npm WARN deprecated urix@0.1.0: Please see https://github.com/lydell/urix#deprecated
npm WARN deprecated resolve-url@0.2.1: https://github.com/lydell/resolve-url#deprecated
npm ERR! code EACCES
npm ERR! syscall symlink
npm ERR! path ../lib/node_modules/gulp-cli/bin/gulp.js
npm ERR! dest /usr/local/bin/gulp
npm ERR! errno -13
npm ERR! Error: EACCES: permission denied, symlink '../lib/node_modules/gulp-cli/bin/gulp.js' -> '/usr/local/bin/gulp'
npm ERR!  [OperationalError: EACCES: permission denied, symlink '../lib/node_modules/gulp-cli/bin/gulp.js' -> '/usr/local/bin/gulp'] {
npm ERR!   cause: [Error: EACCES: permission denied, symlink '../lib/node_modules/gulp-cli/bin/gulp.js' -> '/usr/local/bin/gulp'] {
npm ERR!     errno: -13,
npm ERR!     code: 'EACCES',
npm ERR!     syscall: 'symlink',
npm ERR!     path: '../lib/node_modules/gulp-cli/bin/gulp.js',
npm ERR!     dest: '/usr/local/bin/gulp'
npm ERR!   },
npm ERR!   errno: -13,
npm ERR!   code: 'EACCES',
npm ERR!   syscall: 'symlink',
npm ERR!   path: '../lib/node_modules/gulp-cli/bin/gulp.js',
npm ERR!   dest: '/usr/local/bin/gulp'
npm ERR! }
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! The operation was rejected by your operating system.
npm ERR! It is likely you do not have the permissions to access this file as the current user
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! If you believe this might be a permissions issue, please double-check the
npm ERR! permissions of the file and its containing directories, or try running
npm ERR! the command again as root/Administrator.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/HeatherDannyelle/.npm/_logs/2020-11-21T14_21_43_400Z-debug.log
```

Comment: have you tried with sudo ?